# base table or view not found in laravel after create category and redirect to category.index

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, relationship

i have problem with creating cateogories.
before i change the category relationship to many to many i didnt have problem.

**whene i post new category and after that its redirect to category list page, i got this error:**

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'myblog.category_post' doesn't exist (SQL: select `posts`.*, `category_post`.`category_id` as `pivot_category_id`, `category_post`.`post_id` as `pivot_post_id` from `posts` inner join `category_post` on `posts`.`id` = `category_post`.`post_id` where `category_post`.`category_id` = 1) (View: C:\Users\M0RT3Z4\Desktop\MyBlog\resources\views\admin\category\index.blade.php)

*but the category insert in database. if a record insert in to category table, the category list will not show and i will get error.*

**Post Model:**

namespace App\Models;

use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use Sluggable;
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'body', 'views', 'category_id', 'user_id'
    ];

    public function comment()
    {
        $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
    }

    /**
     * Return the sluggable configuration array for this model.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function sluggable(): array
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'title'
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function hastags($id)
    {
        return in_array($id, $this->tags()->pluck('id')->toArray());
    }

    public function hascategories($id)
    {
        return in_array($id,$this->category()->pluck('id')->toArray());
    }
}
```

**Category Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    use Sluggable;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name','slug'
    ];

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
    }

    /**
     * Return the sluggable configuration array for this model.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function sluggable(): array
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'name'
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

*CategoryController:*

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Models\Category;
use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $post = Post::all();
        $cats = Category::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(10);
        return view('admin.category.index',compact(['cats','post']));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.category.create');
    }

    public function show(Category $category)
    {
        return view('admin.category.show',compact('category'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|min:3|unique:categories',
        ]);

        $cat = new Category();
        $cat->name = $request->name;
        $cat->slug = $request->slug;
        $cat->save();

        Session::flash('success','Category Created Successfully');

        return redirect()->route('admin.category.index');
    }

    public function edit(Category $category)
    {
        return view('admin.category.edit',compact('category'));
    }

    public function update(Category $category,Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|min:3|unique:categories',
        ]);

        $category->name = $request->name;
        $category->save();

        Session::flash('update','Category Updated Successfully');

        return redirect()->route('admin.category.index');
    }

    public function destroy(Category $category)
    {
        $category->delete();

        Session::flash('delete','Category Deleted Successfully');

        return redirect()->route('admin.category.index');
    }
}
```

*categories migration:*

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
}
```

*post_category migration*

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostCategory extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('post_category', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedInteger('post_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
            $table->foreign('post_id')->on('posts')->references('id')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->on('categories')->references('id')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unique(['post_id', 'category_id']);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('post_category');
    }
}
```

*posts migration*

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title')->unique();
            $table->string('slug')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->text('body');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedInteger('views')->default(0);
            $table->unsignedInteger('category_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use best practice for migration naming convention to avoid this issue

rename `create_post_category` to `category_post` (alphabetical order)

or you can specify within `$this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'category_post')` additional arguments for the pivot table and keys

Comment: i've updated the answer to include the pivot table, try it, if it didn't work then make sure that you ran `php artisan migrate`